# mysql load_file() function always return null for symbolic link

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, symbolic-link, symlink, mysql5.5

i have installed new database server on ubuntu

mysql version is 5.5.35

im trying to execute `select load_file('/usr/home/aaa.com/medya_data/ver.txt')` 
and im sure ver.txt file is exist but `medya_data` folder mapped as symbolic link

if i try without symbolic link folder the query is working well

here is my.cnf file :

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
# datadir               = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /data/mysql/tmp
# lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
# skip-external-locking
#
symbolic-links  = 1

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address          = 0.0.0.0
#
# * Fine Tuning
```

thanks for advice

Answer (score -1):

You can use a hardlink instead if the symlink path is on the same file system.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more ? This answer is not clear enough as is...Thank you